# Workflow Rule for formula

Tags: workflow

I have created the custom field called `Payment_Method__c(picklist Type) Values(Default (A/R & A/P),Contrassegno,RIBA,Bonifico Bancario,Rimessa Diretta)` and  `JDE_Payment_method__c` in order, `JDE_Payment_method__c` field is created as the Formula field in Salesforce.

Formula is:

```
CASE(Payment_Method__c , 
    "Default (A/R & A/P)","", 
    "Contrassegno","*", 
    "RIBA","+", 
    "Bonifico Bancario","-", 
    "Rimessa Diretta",":", 
    "")
```

whatever we are choosing the field called `Payment_Method__c` in order while creating and updating the field in order record it automatically populate the value in `JDE_Payment_method__c`

**For example if i choose the value in Bonifico Bancario in `Payment_Method__c` and it automatically update the value in `JDE_Payment_method__c` as - using Formula and so on**

This process will work for both insert and update in the record for order object

**Now I want to change the Formula field to workflow Rule to update(only when Record is created)**

For this Scenario:

[image: Workflow Rule creation]

**what i  have to specify the value in Rule Criteria , after checking the rule criteria, it have to update the field in JDE_Payment_method__c  in order object for these different types of picklist values**

**I want a single Workflow Rule to achieve my target**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can simply use "True" in rule criteria, example below. But this won't solve your problem.**

[image]

**You need to create a new "Text Field" and use this text field to store the initial value ( value of the field when the record is created), because formula field cannot be accessed in workflow rule.**

[image]

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: why you posted,But this won't solve your problem. , if not solve means , please suggest another solution@Rahul Yadavansh

Comment: Please do try, I have performed this in my dev org and its working as desired.

Comment: then edit the  answer and remove ' this won't solve your problem' thats why i want, everybody seeing your answer @Rahul Yadavansh